# Download file link inside grid JQgrid

Tags: jqgrid

im new about using jqgrid, and i have a question about jqgrid, hoping help to resolve my question :)

I have a grid that contain a column 'Download File', the column filed with data i load from database and the value is local url that direct to the document like 'file:///D:/Download Folder/File.xlsx'.
I have 2 .js, one is gridview .js and other is model.js. I create link inside model.js using the data and call it inside gridview.js in colModel.

This is my code

```
//Model.js
val.fileDirText = '<a href="'+val.fileDir+'" target="_blank">'+fileName'</a>';

//Gridview.js
{name: 'fileDirText',width:250,sortable:false}
```

The Download File column is has a underline and hand symbol if i hover to it but there is no action when i click, open in new tab, and open in new window, but it can copy link.

So how to make the link is clickable and start download the file?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   /*Use my code as reference, it may help.*/
    colNames : ["Certificate"],
    colModel: [
   { name: "Certificate", index: "Certificate", align: "center", formatter: downloadLink },
    ],

        function downloadLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var MTJobRoleId = rowObject.MTJobRoleId;

     return "<a href='../Templates/Certificate129821/GENERAL_ENGLISH_1_100720181922.pdf' download=''>View Certificate</a>";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.